# phpunit [laravel] and global database transactions per whole testing class

Tags: php, unit-testing, transactions, phpunit

I'm trying to test functions working with database (oracle), and I want to wrap all tests in one test class in single DB transaction.

**Code**:

```
class CreatingUsersTest extends TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        parent::createApplication();
        \DB::connection('oracle_rpc')->beginTransaction();
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();
    }

    //.... creating user and manipulating with it.....

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {
        \DB::connection('oracle_rpc')->rollBack();
        parent::tearDownAfterClass();
    }
}
```

One of testing functions throws an error.
But the data which was created before this error stays in DB, i.e. there is no real `rollBack()` happens.

Comment: Depending on the severity of the error, it won't reach your rollback statement. I feel like you're over complicating things, laravel provides a rollback option for the database out of the box when doing tests [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test).

Comment: >> Depending on the severity of the error, it won't reach your rollback statement    
    
But if transaction is started, and there is no `commit` called, transaction should not be committed automatically, right?    


>> laravel provides a rollback option for the database out of the box when doing tests     
  

It is `per-test` transactions, but i want to use single transaction per whole test class, because there are dependencies between tests